# $ Cov(X,Y)=-5, \, Cov(X,Z)=2, \, Cov(Y,Z)=2 $. What can we say about $\sigma^2 (X+Y+Z)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, variance, covariance, correlation

I found this question in some exam, but i don't have the answer. I tried to solve it myself, but i'm afraid i got stuck.

We these random $3$ variables $X,Y,Z$, and we know that:
$$
Cov(X,Y)=-5, \quad Cov(X,Z)=2, \quad Cov(Y,Z)=2
$$
Select the correct answer:

1. $\sigma^2 (X+Y+Z) < \sigma^2(X) + \sigma^2(Y) - \sigma^2(Z)$
2. $\sigma^2 (X+Y+Z) = \sigma^2(X) + \sigma^2(Y) + \sigma^2(Z)$
3. $\sigma^2 (X+Y+Z) > \sigma^2(X) + \sigma^2(Y) + \sigma^2(Z)$
4. $\sigma^2 (X-Y+Z) < \sigma^2(X) + \sigma^2(Y) + \sigma^2(Z)$
5. $\sigma^2 (-X+Y+Z) > \sigma^2(X) + \sigma^2(Y) + \sigma^2(Z)$

$$$$
Here's what i calculated so far:

First of all, i know that: $\sigma^2 (\pm X \pm Y \pm Z)=\sigma^2 (X) + \sigma^2(Y) + \sigma^2( Z)$, so i don't mind about the signs so that's why option $1$ is out (yeah, particularly now i just ignored the fact they are correlated. Of course in our case i must include to covariances).

Now, i tried to "split" the variance of $\sigma^2 (X+Y+Z)$ in $3$ different way (i skipped some steps, represented as "..."):

1. $\sigma^2 ((X+Y)+Z)=\sigma^2(X+Y)+\sigma^2(Z)+2Cov(X+Y,Z)=...=
   \sigma^2(X) + \sigma^2(Y) + \sigma^2(Z)+\boldsymbol{(2Cov(X+Y,Z)-10)}$
2. $\sigma^2 (X+(Y+Z))=\sigma^2(X)+\sigma^2(Y+Z)+2Cov(X,Y+Z)=...=
   \sigma^2(X) + \sigma^2(Y) + \sigma^2(Z)+\boldsymbol{(4+2Cov(X,Y+Z))}$
3. $\sigma^2 ((X+Z)+Y)=\sigma^2(X+Z)+\sigma^2(Y)+2Cov(X+Z,Y)=...=
   \sigma^2(X) + \sigma^2(Y) + \sigma^2(Z)+\boldsymbol{(4+2Cov(X+Z,Y)}$

and since all these $3$ bold parts are actually equal, i managed to conclude that:
$$
Cov(X,Y+Z)= Cov(X+Z,Y), \quad Cov(X+Y,Z)=7+Cov(X+Z,Y)=7+Cov(X,Y+Z)
$$

But i don't really see how can i move forward from here. What do you think the correct answer is? Can you give me a lead or a hint? Do you agree with my conclutions so far?

Comment: Just use $\text{Var}(X \pm Y \pm Z) = \text{Cov}(X\pm Y \pm Z, X\pm Y\pm Z)$ and  linearity of Cov in both arguments. What do you get?

Comment: oh man, i think i just got it.. it's easier than i thought.
$$
\sigma^2(X+Y+Z)=
\sigma^2(X)+\sigma^2(Y)+\sigma^2(Z)+2Cov(X,Y)+2Cov(X,Z)+2Cov(Y,Z)=
\sigma^2(X)+\sigma^2(Y)+\sigma^2(Z)+2\Big(Cov(X,Y)+Cov(X,Z)+Cov(Y,Z)\Big)=
\sigma^2(X)+\sigma^2(Y)+\sigma^2(Z)+2(-5+2+2)=
\sigma^2(X)+\sigma^2(Y)+\sigma^2(Z)-2 <
\sigma^2(X)+\sigma^2(Y)+\sigma^2(Z)
$$

and since $\sigma^2(Z) \geq 0$, we get that $\sigma^2(X)+\sigma^2(Y)+\sigma^2(Z) < \sigma^2(X)+\sigma^2(Y)-\sigma^2(Z)$.

Final: $\sigma^2(X+Y+Z) < \sigma^2(X)+\sigma^2(Y)-\sigma^2(Z)$.

So **number 1** is the correct answer. Right?

Comment: Your transformation is correct, but $\sigma^2(X)+\sigma^2(Y)+\sigma^2(Z) < \sigma^2(X)+\sigma^2(Y)-\sigma^2(Z)$ obviusly not as $\sigma^2(Z) \geq 0$. But it holds $\sigma^2(X)+\sigma^2(Y)+\sigma^2(Z) \ge \sigma^2(X)+\sigma^2(Y)-\sigma^2(Z)$. Actually if 1. holds or not depends on $\sigma^2(Z)$, so it's undecidable. 2. and 3. are false obviously, so check 4. and 5.

Comment: My bad. I accidently made a wrong move. The right answer is surely 5. I miscalculated something earlier..